# Randomly putting a circle in a box

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am making a game and I am trying to randomly put a circle in a rectangle. But, it seems that the circle sometimes appear outside of the rectangle. What would I have to do so the circle ALWAYS appears somewhere in the rectangle?

this is my code:

rectangle:

```
--bottom
local floor = display.newRect(0, display.contentCenterY/.665, display.contentWidth*2, 10)
physics.addBody(floor, "static", {density = 1, friction = 1, bounce = 0})
--top
local floor = display.newRect(0, display.contentCenterY/2, display.contentWidth*2, 10)
physics.addBody(floor, "static", {density = 1, friction = 1, bounce = 0})
--right
local floor = display.newRect(display.contentCenterX*2, display.contentCenterY/1, 10, display.contentHeight/2)
physics.addBody(floor, "static", {density = 1, friction = 1, bounce = 0})
--left
local floor = display.newRect(0, display.contentCenterY/1, 10, display.contentHeight/2)
physics.addBody(floor, "static", {density = 1, friction = 1, bounce = 0})
```

circle:

```
--Small sprites--
local randomX = math.random(1,display.contentCenterX*2)
local randomY = math.random(1, display.contentCenterY*2)

local smallSprite = display.newCircle(randomX, randomY, display.contentWidth/100)
smallSprite:setFillColor(1, 1, .3, 1) --This will set the fill color to transparent
smallSprite.strokeWidth = 7 --This is the width of the outline of the circle
smallSprite:setStrokeColor(.1,1,1) --This is the color of the outline
smallSprite = display.newGroup(smallSprite)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is easy, you know where the sides of rectangle are (call them rigth, left, top and bottom) and the radius of circle, so: `randomX` will be between `left+radius` and `right-radius`, and `randomY` will be between `top+radius` and `bottom-radius`

```
-- remember to add/substract the width of the walls
local left = 0 + 10
local right = display.contentCenterX * 2 - 10

--Small sprites--
local randomX = math.random(left+radius,right-radius)
local randomY = math.random(top+radius, bottom-radius)
```

You can generate a random number between any 2 numbers of your choice.
Remember also you can use display.contentHeight and display.contentWidth

As a tip, you can add at the beginning of your file a section with variables like:

```
-- Variables
local w = display.contentWidth
local h = display.contentHeight
local centerX = display.contentCenterX
local centerY = display.contentCenterY
```

So you can use only centerX instead of display.contentCenterX

Comment: how would i do that? because, i thought i made it like that, but it seems it didnt work.